# Why I am getting a special character printed after the recursive DFS?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

I have a simple toy code for Depth First Search, But why I am getting a % after the print?

```
# Definition for a  binary tree node
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
    def dfs(t):
    if t==None:    
        print("",end="")    
    else:    
        print(t.val,end="")        
        dfs(t.left)        
        dfs(t.right)

t=TreeNode(1)
t.left=TreeNode(2)
t.right=TreeNode(3)
t.left.left=TreeNode(4)
t.left.right=TreeNode(5)
t.right.left=TreeNode(6)
t.right.right=TreeNode(7)
dfs(t)
```

Output: 1245367%

Comment: This is yet another reason why you should make a [mcve] -- assuming @user2357112 is right (a safe bet), then during the process of making your example minimal you would have realized that it doesn't actually depend on most of your code at all.

Comment: @DSM thanks! I am new to SO and trying to learn how to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's your shell prompt. Your output doesn't end with a line terminator, so your shell prints its "next command, please" prompt on the same line as your program's output.

Comment: Thanks, and I am using iterm zsh, so -> is actually a special character related to %